# Is there a formula for the number of proper k-colorings of a graph $G$ up to isomorphism?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, reference-request, graph-theory

In Richard Stanley's Algebraic Combinatorics book, he gives a formula for the inequivalent colorings of a set $X$ up to action by some permutation group $G$, namely:

$$ \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{\pi \in G} n^{c(\pi)} $$

where $c(\pi)$ denotes the number of cycles of $\pi$.

From this, if we have a graph $G$ and we would like to study the number of inequivalent k-colorings of $G$ up to automorphism, we can simply apply the formula using $Aut(G)$ as our permutation group, and $V(G)$ as our set.

My question is, can we extend this formula somehow to count the number of *proper* k-colorings of a graph up to action by the graph's automorphism group? If not, have similar methods been used to study this question?

Comment: I would be very much surprised if an easy formula of this kind exists, for it would allow an easy way to check whether the graph is $k$-colourable: simply check if the formula gives the answer $0$ or a positive number. For $k \geq 3$ [this problem is known to be NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity). However, since the P versus NP question has not been settled, this does not prove that no simple formula exists.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn  One has to compute $\rm{Aut}(G)$. Hence, it seems to me, that this argument related to complexity invalid? In addition, the presented formula for all colorings is rather simple but it may contain exponentially many terms as well.

Comment: @Jernej oh, yeah, you're right! Evidently I didn't think it through. Thanks for pointing this out. :-)